Does the practice of voting for a small party, despite the "spoiler effect" in FPTP, to induce changes in a larger party have a name?
I am interesting in reading about this topic and I'm interested if this effect has a well known name that I can look up and read more on.
Consider UKIP and the Conservative Party in the UK. In the early 2000s, UKIP were a small single-issue party. They stood against candidates of the Conservative Party, and thanks to FPTP, there was a risk of a spoiler effect where areas might have elected other parties despite Conservative + UKIP getting more votes in that area.
As a result of this (arguably), the Conservatives promised a referendum of EU membership. Something they probably wouldn't have done without the risk of many UKIP candidates taking enough votes for the Conservatives to lose seats.
"You won't win and you might let (big party A) win."
"Maybe (big party B) should take us more seriously and include (issue) in their manifesto. We believe in (issue) so much we're willing to let (big party A) win."

It's related to tactical voting where you consider how other people vote in order to achieve an election result to your likening. Here it is more the reverse where other should consider how you could vote and there you achieve a result (not necessary an election one) to your likening. Maybe then it would be a "kind of blackmail to vote tactical to hurt somebody"?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protest_vote
